# Mono - Unhandled Exception Error Visualbasic on Linux

Tags: mono

I am getting an error when trying to run an exe

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NodeLink.MainModule' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>     at NodeLink.MainModule..cctor () [0x0003e] in <1c1efda0a57d461d88830c1847dd8a31>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NodeLink.MainModule' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>     at NodeLink.MainModule..cctor () [0x0003e] in <1c1efda0a57d461d88830c1847dd8a31>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I am new to mono and not really sure what is wrong
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing the code, there's not much we could do to help.

Comment: What code are you referring to?